# How to make non-editable non-savable PDF into editable and savable?

Tags: macos, pdf, adobe

My university provides forms such as [here](http://sal.aalto.fi/files/opinnot/kurssit/mat-2.kandi/aihehakemus.pdf) in non-editable and non-savable form (it also has some odd sign such as 'Print form' that I need to remove). I am able to print the document with Illustrator and edit it this way even without the *'Print form'* but if I print it through browser, it has this odd sign *'Print form'*. I don't want to rewrite things again-and-again. Is it possible to make the PDF so that people without Illustrator were able to edit and save it?

1. Is there a way to make the PDF editable and savable in OS X?
2. Is the only way do it with Adobe Illustrator?

Answer (score 1):

Preview in Mountain Lion allows you to inform all the fields available in that form. If you need to actually remove fields, you can use Infix to convert it to a standard PDF.

I just tried on the link you gave and it worked perfectly.

Comment: What is Infix? I tested the preview in Mountain Lion and I am able to save and edit -- but I am not able to remove the *'Print form'* thing and the title gets under the form.

Comment: Infix is PDF editor created by Inceni.